# Gdb and dollars in identifiers

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, clang

I'd like to debug a program that uses the dollars in identifiers extension.

Take

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int $a = 42, b= 43;
    printf("%d %d\n", $a, b);
}
```

for a simplified example. If I run it under gdb, I can inspect `b` using `p b`, but for `p $a` I get `void`. I can only show the value with `info locals`.

Is there a way to refer to $-containing identifiers in gdb?

Comment: @chqrlie Tried all slashes, double quotes, single quotes, but didn't get it to work yet. :/

Comment: Does `main::$a` work?

Comment: ".. uses the dollars in identifiers extension." -- I can think of no good reason to use such extension. One solution is to simply get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gdb` interprets the initial `$` in `p $a` before parsing the expression to print.

Note however that it only does this for the initial `$`: if the `$` sign appears in the middle of a symbol, (eg: `p a$1`) the variable is printed correctly.

A work-around for local variables whose name start with a dollar-sign is to print all local variables with

```
info locals
```